# How can I upgrade SSA embedded on an HP 380 G9

Tags: raid, hp

I recently purchased a DL380 G9 server with an additional P840ar array controller. The built in SSA doesn't seem to support the P840. It has a list of supported devices, and P840 is not listed. I was able to download a bootable copy of SSA and it detects the controller, back plate, drives and all.

How do I update the embedded application on the server? I don't want to rely on a boot flash drive if I need to make changes in the future.

Comment: What are you on about? of course SSA supports the P-everything, I have multiple DL380 Gen9's with that exact controller and they definitely work - and you update everything with the SPP as per every other bit of HPE kit - layer 8 problem I think.

Comment: The version of SSA that is currently embedded on the server does not support that card. If SPP will update those embedded applications, that is exactly what I was looking for. I am trying that now.

Comment: There's literally no chance that that's the case though, the P840ar was shipped on day-one of the Gen9 servers, it was built in - there's something else 'funny' going on.

Answer (score 2):

Update your [Intelligent Provisioning](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=1008862660&swItemId=MTX_95355b8061cc4988862f2faa0b&swEnvOid=4184) using the "Recovery Media" ISO from HP.

Or download the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/) to run your array setup.

Answer (score 1):

To update for the lates version look for

"Inteligent provisioning recovery media" in support center. Choose the

Currently the last one is [2.80 2020, feb 25th](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_6912b1ab040b4e23952cba99c2)

That's an ISO image. You can boot from it using ILO remote media, or create a bootable USB for example with [USB Key utility for Windows](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_360731071b404454b454390208), or burn a DVD.

It will automatically update the ROM with the provisioning utility that includes the SSA.